# Internet not working in Anbox on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, android

The internet has worked previously
but it has stopped working after restarting.
Result of `anbox system-info`:

```
$ anbox system-info
version: 4
snap-revision: 158
cpu:
  arch:  x86
  brand: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz
  features: 
    - aes
    - sse4_1
    - sse4_2
    - avx
    - avx2
os:
  name: Ubuntu
  version: 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
  snap-based: true
kernel:
  version: Linux version 4.15.0-43-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-001) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018
  binder: true
  ashmem: true
graphics:
  egl:
    vendor: Mesa Project
    version: 1.4 (DRI2)
    extensions:
      - EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync
      - EGL_CHROMIUM_sync_control
      - EGL_EXT_buffer_age
      - EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness
      - EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import
      - EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import_modifiers
      - EGL_IMG_context_priority
      - EGL_KHR_config_attribs
      - EGL_KHR_create_context
      - EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error
      - EGL_KHR_fence_sync
      - EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses
      - EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace
      - EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
      - EGL_KHR_image
      - EGL_KHR_image_base
      - EGL_KHR_image_pixmap
      - EGL_KHR_no_config_context
      - EGL_KHR_reusable_sync
      - EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context
      - EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float
      - EGL_KHR_wait_sync
      - EGL_MESA_configless_context
      - EGL_MESA_drm_image
      - EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export
      - EGL_NOK_texture_from_pixmap
      - EGL_WL_bind_wayland_display
  gles2:
    vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
    vendor: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 18.0.5
    extensions:
      - GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a
      - GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3
      - GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5
      - GL_APPLE_texture_max_level
      - GL_EXT_blend_func_extended
      - GL_EXT_blend_minmax
      - GL_EXT_buffer_storage
      - GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance
      - GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
      - GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture
      - GL_EXT_copy_image
      - GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
      - GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
      - GL_EXT_draw_buffers
      - GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
      - GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex
      - GL_EXT_frag_depth
      - GL_EXT_geometry_point_size
      - GL_EXT_geometry_shader
      - GL_EXT_gpu_shader5
      - GL_EXT_map_buffer_range
      - GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
      - GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean
      - GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp
      - GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box
      - GL_EXT_read_format_bgra
      - GL_EXT_robustness
      - GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
      - GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch
      - GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix
      - GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks
      - GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical
      - GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size
      - GL_EXT_tessellation_shader
      - GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp
      - GL_EXT_texture_buffer
      - GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
      - GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array
      - GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
      - GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
      - GL_EXT_texture_rg
      - GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
      - GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
      - GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
      - GL_INTEL_conservative_rasterization
      - GL_INTEL_performance_query
      - GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
      - GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
      - GL_KHR_context_flush_control
      - GL_KHR_debug
      - GL_KHR_no_error
      - GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior
      - GL_KHR_robustness
      - GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr
      - GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d
      - GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions
      - GL_NV_draw_buffers
      - GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
      - GL_NV_image_formats
      - GL_NV_read_buffer
      - GL_NV_read_depth
      - GL_NV_read_depth_stencil
      - GL_NV_read_stencil
      - GL_OES_EGL_image
      - GL_OES_EGL_image_external
      - GL_OES_EGL_sync
      - GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
      - GL_OES_copy_image
      - GL_OES_depth24
      - GL_OES_depth_texture
      - GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map
      - GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed
      - GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex
      - GL_OES_element_index_uint
      - GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
      - GL_OES_geometry_point_size
      - GL_OES_geometry_shader
      - GL_OES_get_program_binary
      - GL_OES_gpu_shader5
      - GL_OES_mapbuffer
      - GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
      - GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box
      - GL_OES_required_internalformat
      - GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
      - GL_OES_sample_shading
      - GL_OES_sample_variables
      - GL_OES_shader_image_atomic
      - GL_OES_shader_io_blocks
      - GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation
      - GL_OES_standard_derivatives
      - GL_OES_stencil8
      - GL_OES_surfaceless_context
      - GL_OES_tessellation_point_size
      - GL_OES_tessellation_shader
      - GL_OES_texture_3D
      - GL_OES_texture_border_clamp
      - GL_OES_texture_buffer
      - GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array
      - GL_OES_texture_float
      - GL_OES_texture_float_linear
      - GL_OES_texture_half_float
      - GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
      - GL_OES_texture_npot
      - GL_OES_texture_stencil8
      - GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array
      - GL_OES_vertex_array_object
      - GL_OES_vertex_half_float
      - GL_OES_viewport_array
```

Opening any webpage in the WebView Tester gives the error `net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`. There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1012) on the github page regarding this but no solution. Any pointers in this regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I encountered the same problem on my Ubutnu 18.04.
I think on linux following would work.
First restart the anbox by following command on terminal

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.anbox.container-manager.service
```

Then download the script from this github page [Anbox-Bridge](https://github.com/Debyzulkarnain/anbox-bridge/)
Then extract the script if you download from link or just jump to the folder of script probably named as "anbox-bridge"
Then run following commands

```
chmod +x anbox-bridge.sh
./anbox-bridge.sh
```

Beware that these commands should be in superuser mode.
These process have to be run every time you restart your computer.
These things work on me and I am not sure this would work for you! :)

Comment: Doesn't work, the script has no effect. After start/reload it `bridge link` still shows nothing

Comment: Plus, anbox already ship with a default vlan interface anbox0: https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/advanced/network_configuration.html. Why do we need to set up another using the script?

Comment: I am not absolute expert. I just shared what worked for me. Sorry, I cannot help you with it.

Comment: Just restarting the service fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

**This solution works fine.**
Only you would be doing this every time you restart your computer

```
adb shell
su
ip route add default dev eth0 via 192.168.250.1
ip rule add pref 32766 table main
ip rule add pref 32767 table local
```

Answer (score 1):

3 years later the solution is still, restart AnBox:

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.anbox.container-manager.service
```

I did not need to run the script.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks for such an amazing solution. I restart the service as you said, and, subsequently, I run Anbox. Like a charm. (not so much effort)